# Is QEMU's `savevm` transactional/atomic?

Tags: qemu, snapshot

I've looked into [QEMU documentation](https://qemu-project.gitlab.io/qemu/system/monitor.html) but found no answers.

I'm using QEMU's `savevm` command in monitor to save the vm snapshot. For simplicity i use the same tag (it's hightly unlikely to save a new snapshot and then remove existing snapshot due to lack of QEMU admin utils on the device). Is `savevm` transactional/atomic? Can it happen that no new snapshot is saved, but the existing one (to be overwritten) is corrupted or broken?

How can i understand `savevm` call was not successful (if it's the case)?

Answer (score 0):

Simply, savevm if you didn't give it a name or id, it will create a new one,
you can check it by this command

```
(qemu) info snapshots
```

but if you want to overwrite it, just put an old name or id,

```
(qemu) savevm `old_snapshot_name`
```

the attached link talked about that in more detail
[here](https://wiki.qemu.org/Features/SnapshottingImprovements)